# how to count the number of words in a line in perl?

Tags: perl

I know I could write my own while loop along with regex to count the words in a line. But, I am processing like 1000 lines and I dont want to run this loop each and every time. So, I was wondering is there any way to count the words in the line in perl.

Comment: define word: Is "composite-word" 1 word? Is "Identifier1$subclass" 1 word?

Answer (score 4):

1000 times is not a significant number to a modern computer.  In general, write the code that makes sense to you, and then, *if* there is a performance problem, worry about optimization.

To count words, first you need to decide what is a word.  One approach is to match groups of consecutive word characters, but that counts "it's" as two words.
Another is to match groups of consecutive non-whitespace, but that counts "phrase - phrase" as three words.  Once you have a regex that matches a word, you can count words like this (using consecutive word characters for this example):

```
scalar( () = $line =~ /\w+/g )
```

Comment: `perl -E 'say scalar(() = "foo bar" =~ /\w+/)'` gives me `1`, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @zoul: sorry, I forgot the /g

Answer (score 2):

How about splitting the line on one or more non-word characters and counting the size of the resulting array?

```
$ echo "one, two, three" | perl -nE "say scalar split /\W+/"
3
```

As a sub that would be:

```
# say count_words 'foo bar' => 2
sub count_words { scalar split /\W+/, shift }
```

To get rid of the leading space problem spotted by ysth, you can filter out the empty segments:

```
$ echo " one, two, three" | perl -nE 'say scalar grep {length $_} split /\W+/'
3
```

…or shave the input string:

```
$ echo " one, two, three" | perl -nE 's/^\W+//; say scalar split /\W+/'
3
```

Comment: that counts " one, two, three" as four words

Comment: `grep {length $_}` so you count `0` as a word